# ImportError: Couldn't import Django?

Tags: django, deployment

when run with command python manage.py runserver crashes with the error The virtual environment is active, for some reason it does not see the packages that they are all installed.Virtual environment active packages all installed

when run with command python manage.py runserver crashes with the error The virtual environment is active, for some reason it does not see the packages that they are all installed.Virtual environment active packages all installed

Comment: Please clarify your specific problem or provide additional details to highlight exactly what you need. As it's currently written, it's hard to tell exactly what you're asking.

Answer (score 0):

If you are using VScode, try to change your python interpreter from your default to your virtual environment one by opening the Command Palette ( CTRL+SHIFT+P ) and selecting > Python: Select Interpreter. Here’s the [docs](https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/python/environments) about using Python environments with VScode.